# Free text editor that closes brackets automatically (replacement for Sublime Text)

Tags: gratis, linux, text-editor

I'm looking for a free text editor on Linux that has similar functionality of [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

I really only care about how it closes brackets automatically and such things.
So here are the things I want:

- It is free
- It auto-closes parentheses, brackets, etc.
- It should work on Linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Atom](https://atom.io/) can be considered as a replacement for Sublime Text, and features automatic closing of parentheses and brackets, just like Sublime does.

Answer (score 4):

A lightweight and very capable text editor that does what you need is [Geany](http://www.geany.org/). In the Edit>Preferences, Editor, section, Completions - you can specify on what type of parentheses or brackets you want to activate auto-closing.

Installation on Ubuntu:

`sudo apt-get install geany`

In addition to auto-close, Geany does very well auto-completion based on words already present in a given document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/):

- free and open source
- Windows, Mac OS and Linux
- auto-closes parentheses, brackets
- support a huge amount of languages and plenty of features

Comment: Sorry, but Eclipse is not a text editor. This is like recommending a chainsaw to someone that asked for a kitchen knife.

Comment: A chainsaw cannot do everything a kitchen knife can. I see Eclipse as a Swiss Army knife. The OP didn't mention lightweight as a requirement.

Comment: He asked for a text editor though, both in the question title and the text, and used the `text-editors` tag. Eclipse is simply not a text editor, it's a full blown IDE. A text editor can typically be launched in mere seconds, open any file without first creating a "project", which enables an entirely different way of working. "Lightweight" wasn't an explicit requirement, but "text editor" was, and Eclipse is not a text editor.

Comment: Well that is your definition of a text editor.

Comment: Please name *one* source that calls Eclipse a "text editor". Here's two that don't: [Wikipedia:List of text Editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_text_editors), [Wikipedia: Comparison of Text Editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors)

Comment: (my last comment) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor : "A text editor is a type of program used for editing plain text files". Eclipse can be used for editing plain text files. Eclipse is subsequently a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) is light and free text editor. It has features mentioned: look like ST3, auto-closing of brackets `(){}[]`.

Windows, Linux, OSX. Note: for Linux you need to have Python 3 in OS and set path to Python files by option "pylib".

Answer (score 0):

[Kate](https://kate-editor.org/about/) is a beautiful text editor that works well on Ubuntu, even if it will bring some Qt dependencies with it. It can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install kate
```

In the Settings>Configure Kate..., you can activate in the "Editing"/"General" tab the "Enable automatic brackets" option.

[image: Editing options]